# RedisCacheManager autowired in code but not working as expected

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, caching, redis, spring-cache

I am caching data by using @Cacheable(value="bus_availability", key="#sourceCity")   spring annotation in Redis using spring.
But whenever trying to access it using RedisCacheManager I not getting results.
Like redisCacheManager.getCacheNames() returning empty array.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong "bus_availability" will be cache name.

Answer (score 0):

I done some research and solved this. I was calling method from same class so proxy concept was not applying to bean.
So now I moved it in another bean and its working fine now